# How to scale x and y coordinates of a span over an image as the image resizes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I threw together a quick fiddle of what I'm talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/4zokey2f/1/.

Notice if you drag the corner of your browser the image changes size but the span (red box over the tent) does not stay over the tent as the image is resizing. It's worth noting that in my problem I'm passing the x and y values inline like `style={left: this.state.xValue, top: this.state.yValue}` (it's a react component so those are just stored in local state).

I have the original image size that the initial x and y are calculated from, I just don't know the proper way to scale them with the image resize?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue before when I was working on my friend's school project. What I do is center the `background-position` (vertical & horizontal) for both elements, like in your case the `figure` & `span`. Once both are centered, I use `vw` & `vh` to adjust the message box. You can check this updated fiddle of yours https://jsfiddle.net/4zokey2f/2/ also, I add `min-width` & `max-width` on the holder/container, just to add some boundaries or limits. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably try to use something like [canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_intro.asp) or [svg](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp) to generate the image on the fly.

**Canvas example:**

```
<img id="parados" 
src="http://www.thatdrop.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/parados-700x694.jpg" 
alt="The Scream" style="display: none">

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="694"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("parados");
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(650,500,50,50);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("1",660,540);
  };
</script>

<style>
   canvas {
      width: 100%
   }
</style>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/PantsStatusZero/2g612hLn/1/